# Find all the left cosets of $\langle3\rangle$ in $\Bbb{Z}_{18}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Find all the left cosets of $\langle3\rangle$ in $\Bbb{Z}_{18}$.

This is a question my prof made up and I'm not sure what the full answer is.

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: Still not sure how to properly format this

Answer (score 3):

The number of distinct left cosets of $\langle 3 \rangle$ in $\Bbb{Z}_{18}$ is $$\frac{\vert G \vert}{\vert \langle 3 \rangle \vert}=\frac{18}{6}=3$$

They are $$0+\langle 3 \rangle=\langle 3 \rangle=\{3,6,9,12,15,0\}=a+\langle 3 \rangle\;; a \in \langle 3 \rangle$$

$$1+\langle 3 \rangle=\{4,7,10,13,16,1\}=4+\langle 3 \rangle=7+\langle 3 \rangle=10+\langle 3 \rangle=13+\langle 3 \rangle=16+\langle 3 \rangle$$

$$2+\langle 3\rangle=\{5,8,11,14,17,2\}=5+\langle 3 \rangle=8+\langle 3 \rangle=11+\langle 3 \rangle=14+\langle 3 \rangle=17+\langle 3 \rangle$$

Comment: +1. 1) How do you know that $|\langle3\rangle|=6$? 2) For the first equation did you use Lagrange's Theorem?

Comment: order of $3$ is six, so order of the cyclic subgroup generated by $3$ is also six

Comment: Thanks. Lastly, why did you sum the first elements for the left cosets? Why can not be $4+\langle3\rangle$ etc?

Comment: Our task is to find $a +\langle 3 \rangle$ for $a \in G$, if $a \in \langle 3 \rangle$ then $a+\langle 3 \rangle=\langle 3 \rangle$. To find  others   we start with $a=1$ and $a=2$ and so on.. The order is irrelevant, you may start with $4+\langle 3 \rangle$

Comment: But we say that there are three left cosets, no more. So I do not understand why $a\in G$.

Comment: There are three **distinct** left cosets. By definition, left coset of $\langle 3 \rangle$  in $\Bbb{Z}_{18}$ means $$a+\langle 3 \rangle=\{a+h : h \in \langle 3 \rangle\}$$ where $a \in \Bbb{Z}_{18}$